# ReleaseNotes returns 'null' for Android

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

In my project I have used flutter package [new_version](https://pub.dev/packages/new_version), And till now it was working perfectly fine. But now its not working as the "Release Notes" from play store returns null.
The error is as follows

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. E/flutter (10282): Receiver: null E/flutter (10282): Tried calling: [](1) E/flutter (10282): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5) E/flutter (10282): #1      NewVersion._getAndroidStoreVersion (package:new_version/new_version.dart:197:37) E/flutter (10282): <asynchronous suspension>`

Release notes are the only responsible for this error.

As its showing error at this line:
`releaseNotes = data[1][2][144][1][1];` in new_version.dart(line: 197) file.
I just tried changing these indexes in this file but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, since the new playstore web design its not showing whats new anymore. I crossed checked this with my own application which have whats new text in mobile but on playstore is not showing this text.

I even tried searching the text from my whats new in source code of play store listing page. But it's not even there. So I am afraid this release notes field is no longer available.

**Suggestion**

You can still solve this issue by two ways.

1. Create a table inside you db with 4 fields named versionCode, Platform, forceUpdate & releaseNotes. Here you can add your update data, use this data to show custom modals and keep the history of each release. You can use forceUpdate field to provide the functionality to check if this update is must for user or not.
2. Create a json with same 4 values & host it on your server. You can read this json from within your app.

After this you can write your own dialog code or use some package like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_update_dialog.

I my opinion these two solutions are more accurate, scalable & future proof.

Comment: After checking I found out that there release notes field is no longer available, so do you have any idea for solving this issue or is there any other optional package that will work here.

Comment: @MohsinPatel, I don't think this is possible now as the data is not available on the page itself so there is no way to read it from play store page. But I have updated my answer with some suggestions. You can try those.

Comment: @Akash Kumar thanks for the solution I will try those suggestions.